# How to import local classes in python

Tags: python, class, import, visual-studio-code

I have a rather large project in python, so I'm breaking out my custom classes into their own .py files. Many of these classes use other custom classes as an input argument. When I import the custom class using `From custom_file Import CustomClass` the (I think IntelliSense feature) of VS Code cannot recognize properties and methods of the locally imported classes like it does for the global imports (numpy, matplotlib, etc.).

What is the best way to set up my file structure for a project that has many custom classes? Should I be separating classes into their own files, is it standard to have custom classes as inputs to other custom classes, is there a right way to keep track of all of the available methods and properties of custom classes? (it's cumbersome to keep flipping through files to make sure I'm typing out a property name correctly).

Example file structure:

-Main.py (imports Bolt from bolt)
- bolt.py is a file that contains class Bolt, which requires (length: double, thread: Thread). Bolt imports Thread from the thread
-thread.py is a file that contains a Thread which requires(diameter: double, pitch: int, class: int)

In my Main.py, I have another class that uses Bolt as an input, and in that class, I'd like to get the thread class. To do this, I use `self.bolt.thread.class,` but IntelliSense recommends noting after entering `self.bolt.`

And perhaps from a higher level, is it customary to have classes feed into other classes as inputs rather than doing something like inheriting (I don't know much about this). 
The way I do things for the above example is: (please let me know if this is not the right way of doing things)

```
# File 1 --- thread.py
class Thread:
    def __init__(self, diameter: double, pitch: int, cls: int):
        self.diameter = diameter
        self.pitch = pitch
        self.cls = cls

# File 2 --- bolt.py
from thread import Thread

class Bolt:
    def __init__(self, length: double, thrd: Thread):
        self.length = length
        self.thrd = thrd

# File 3 --- joint.py
from bolt import Bolt

class Joint:
    def __init__(self, num_bolts: int, bolt: Bolt):
        self.num_bolts = num_bolts
        self.bolt = bolt

    def get_thrd_class(self):
        return self.bolt.thrd.cls

# File 4 --- main.py
from joint import Joint
from bolt import Bolt
from thread import Thread

thrd = Thread(.25, 20, 3)
bolt = Bolt(1.25, thrd)
joint = Joint(5, bolt)

cls = joint.get_thread_class()
```

Comment: This looks pretty good to me. Are `thread.py`, `bolt.py`, `joint.py`, and `main.py` all in the same directory?

Comment: Yes, they are all in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

ok, I fixed it. Turns out I was using conda - once I uninstalled that in installed vanilla python 3.7 everything worked as it should.